# maven-metadata.xml build error

Tags: java, spring, maven, build, maven-metadata

I am getting the error below in log whenever I try to build my Spring project.
Could anyone please help me?

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.1.SPR-10124-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (like--//tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to link-->//tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.1.SPR-10124-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 403, Forbidden
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.1.SPR-10124-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from link: //tinkerpop.com/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of tinkerpop-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.1.SPR-10124-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to tinkerpop-repository (link://tinkerpop.com/maven2): Access denied to link---//tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.1.SPR-10124-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 403, Forbidden
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of repository you are using ` link://tinkerpop.com/maven2`? Is this an internal repository manager ? Furthermore the URL looks weird...

Comment: http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.2.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

this repository I didn''t configure anywhere. I don''t know where It is configured

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case I am using Netbeans 7.1.2, I am posting this because maybe someone end up here same as I did.

I tried to configure the proxy options from the GUI, but the documentation says that maven doesn't read those. So I checked the NetBeans FAQ here :

What mainly you have to do is create (if it does not exist) a settings.xml under

```
user.home/.m2/settings.xml
```

if you don't have it you can copy from

netbeans.home/java/maven/conf/settings.xml
then uncomment if you already have it otherwise just fill this section:

```
<proxies>
 <proxy>
   <active>true</active>
   <host>myproxy.host.net</host>
   <port>80</port>
 </proxy>
</proxies>
```

you have to check your proxy configuration and replace it there

Comment: Thanks Ayan. But same error repeating..any other suggestions please